# How to get the value on url in pug

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I have an url like this: `http://localhost/editblog/58a5da1df3ec9614fc9893d3`

and code in pug like this:

```
 input.form-control(type='hidden', name='id', value='')
```

The question is how to get the value on the url and pass it to `value=''`

I've known about `req.params.id` but it is not what could solve my issue

Comment: I'm interpreting that you'd like to render the form with the value baked in on page render. Is this correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you render your pug template you could send any variable as `res.locals` property so it will send to template:

```
app.get('/editblog/:id', function(req, res) {
  res.render('editblog', { title: 'edit blog', id: req.params.id });
});
```

And now you have access to `id` whithin your template:

*editblog.pug*:

```
input.form-control(type='hidden', name='id', value=id)
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe he wanted the url to be the value? Then, instead of render ...id: req.params.id});, it would be render ...url: req.orignalUrl. Then for the input, he would set value=url.