# How to Get a specific question by Id in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a question concerning Mern stack. I have a program which is similar to stackOverflow, where you post a question and someone can reply. At the moment my program is able to post questions and also get a list of all questions. I have a link at each and every questions,so that when you click at any of the questions it should open that specific question. The id of the questions is visible at the rout e.g http://localhost:3000/link/5cae2dda9723ad157c085370. The problem am having is to get the content of that specific question

```
//*this code is able get the list of all questions*//

import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import { EMLINK } from "constants";

const Question = props => (
  <tr>
    <td>{props.question.author_name}</td>
    <td>{props.question.question_title}</td>
    <td>{props.question.question_input}</td>
    <td>
      <Link to={"/link/" + props.question._id}>comment</Link>

    </td>
  </tr>
);

class QuestionList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { questions: [] };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:4000/questions/")
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({ questions: response.data });
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  questionList() {
    return this.state.questions.map(function(currentQuestion, i) {
      return <Question question={currentQuestion} key={i} />;
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Question List</h3>
        <table className="table table-striped" style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Title</th>
              <th>Question</th>
              <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>{this.questionList()}</tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default QuestionList;
```

```
*/The below code is the one that i need to only show one specific question by ID*//

import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

import axios from "axios";
const Questioners = props => (
  <tr>
    <td>{props.question.author_name}</td>
    <td>{props.question.question_title}</td>
    <td>{props.question.question_input}</td>
  </tr>
);
class QuestionLink extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      author_name: "",
      question_title: "",
      question_input: ""

    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Question List</h3>
        <table className="table table-striped" style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Title</th>
              <th>Question</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>{}</tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default QuestionLink;
```

Comment: The dynamic id will be available via `props.match.params.id`...

Answer (score 1):

I've done the following in these scenarios:

1. Take the ID as a parameter to the Component (in this case, QuestionLink)
2. Retrieve the question from your REST API as a get for the particular resource (with ID) in your ComponentDidMount
3. When mounting your react app (top-level component), retrieve the Id from the url. I prefer to use a query string

```js
import { parse } from "querystring";
let values = parse(window.location.search.substring(1));
```

And then mount `<QuestionLink questionId={values["questionId"]} />`

**EDIT:** I haven't used template engines for this, but it should be well suited for this kind of work. You can use something like [pug](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html) for the server side rendering, [pass the id to the view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42280831/how-to-get-the-value-on-url-in-pug) from your middleware, and [render to a react component](https://github.com/pugjs/babel-plugin-transform-react-pug). I'd probably only do this if I did this sort of processing extensively and/or needed information that only the server had.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help, i made it work. i solved the issue as follow

```
<Route
              path="/link/:id"
              render={props => <QuestionLink {...props} />}
            />
```

```
 this.state = {
      currentQuestion: {}
    };
componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:4000/questions/")
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          currentQuestion: response.data.find(elm =>
            elm._id == this.props.match.params.id
          )
        });
      })
```